# Using Tkinter GUI to control the GPIO pins on Raspberry Pi when GUI isn't stored in Pi

Tags: python, ssh, gui, tkinter

Using Tkinter to control the GPIO pins on Raspberry Pi is easy and trivial, but can it be done when GUI is not stored in pi, but to another device. granted the device and Pi are connected to the same network.

Comment: Yes you can create a [server](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTP-server/) on the RPI using, for example, NodeJS with [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rpi-gpio) and then send network [request](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=73WpYMulq2k) from Tkinter for controlling your RPI GPIO

Comment: Using tkinter to control GPIO is like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. WHY??